# Android GPS Provider

Tags: android, gps

I'm developing an android application that involves the detection of the users' location. 
What I would like to know is, how does this -> LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER work?

Does it uses the GPS system in the phone or does it uses the mobile company's area network location?

Whenever I turn on the GPS system in my phone, the map would not load. It will only be able to  detect & pinpoint the location when I deactivate it. I think the application is tapping into the GPRS or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER uses GPS and  LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER uses mobile network. Map application works with both of them, it displays the most accurate data that is available from any of the providers.

Answer (score 0):

In reality, GPS is accompanied with Wi-fi or 3G to location searching because the GPS providers is not always available.